# What is python pass by reference not working?

Tags: python, recursion, pass-by-reference

I have a solution for generating permutations of an array which is as follows:

```
class Solution:
    
    def permuteHelper(self,li,nums,ji,x):
        if len(ji)==x:
            li.append(ji)
            return
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            ji.append(nums[i])
            self.permuteHelper(li,nums[:i]+nums[i+1:],ji,x)
            ji.pop()

    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        li = []
        ji = []
        self.permuteHelper(li,nums,ji,len(nums))
        return li
```

Idea is to use another array that appends each element from original array one by one skipping before appended elements. But when doing it like this, I am getting an output of list of empty lists.

Online I saw someone do the same except they did it like this:

```
class Solution:
    
    def permuteHelper(self,li,nums,ji,x):
        if len(ji)==x:
            li.append(ji)
            return
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            self.permuteHelper(li,nums[:i]+nums[i+1:],ji+[nums[i]],x)

    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        li = []
        ji = []
        self.permuteHelper(li,nums,ji,len(nums))
        return li
```

I have no idea why their solution worked and mine did not, I had the same logic as theirs but I don't understand the difference. Can someone please explain why the second one worked and the first one did not?

Comment: I can't understand what you intend the code to do (what would an input look like, and what should be the expected output?), how it is supposed to accomplish that task, or what any of the variable names are supposed to represent. Also, it appears that this code is part of a class, but I can't understand what the intended purpose of the class is, or why not just write plain functions to do the task.

Comment: That said, Python does not have pass by reference, nor pass by value. It has pass by name, the same as class types (without `ref` or `out`) in C#, or non-primitive types in Java. Please see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html.

Comment: I suggest you put `print(ji)` at the end of the `for` loop in both versions to see the difference.

Comment: your answer is going to mutate both `li` and `ji` as it runs, whereas theirs only mutates `li`, and the `ji` is new list instance for each call to `permuteHelper`

Comment: Can you explain how `append` and `+` are the same logic? One updates the same list. The other returns a new one.

Comment: Python **never** supports pass by reference, this is crucial to understand.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel so, technically, it is called "call by sharing". "Pass by name" implies "call by name" which Python definitely doesn't support. "call by sharing" isn't very widely used, but you hear things like "pass by assignment", "pass by object reference", "pass by object" (e.g. in the Ned Batchelder link, it says "Some people call it call by object, or call by assignment.")

Comment: _I had the same logic as theirs_ What?  No you don't.  Your code calls `append()` and `pop()`, and theirs does not.